# Spring Data + Neo4J + Bolt not working

Tags: maven, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I'm using the example from [SDN4 Cineasts](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-cineasts) as a starting point to build my own application on top of SDN and Neo4J. I want to use the Bolt driver, assuming that it does not need to parse HTTP output and is therefore faster and more secure. (Please correct me if I'm wrong on this point.) The template from the Neo github uses the HTTP driver, and I can't get the example to compile or deploy with the Bolt driver. (I'm building a war, not a jar, so if that makes any difference, please do tell.)

Could someone please either confirm that adding this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
    <version>${neo4j.ogm.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

will fail because the dependency cannot be resolved, and that using any version number higher than 2.0.0 will fail to deploy because of version hell; or alternatively please point out the error(s) of my ways? If you do that, you could also edit `ogm.properties` to read like this (replace `<your-username>` and `<your-password>` as appropriate):

```
driver=org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver
URI=bolt://localhost
username=<your-username>
password=<your-password>
encryption.level=NONE
```

Thanks,

Stephan

**Update:** Following the suggestion by [Luanne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/232671/luanne), I added the following dependencies/properties:

```
<sdn.version>4.1.2.RELEASE</sdn.version>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

but got the following error on deployment:

```
01-Sep-2016 10:04:45.689 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /Users/neut/Documents/Utils/apache-tomcat-8.5.4/webapps/works-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
2016-09-01 10:04:51,365 ERROR pringframework.web.context.ContextLoader: 358 - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/autoproxy/AbstractBeanFactoryAwareAdvisingPostProcessor
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2251)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:810)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1253)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1118)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1962)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:609)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:521)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:534)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:567)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:683)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1445)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:445)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:415)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:101)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4716)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractBeanFactoryAwareAdvisingPostProcessor
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1118)
    ... 40 common frames omitted
01-Sep-2016 10:04:51.372 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
01-Sep-2016 10:04:51.373 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/works-1.0-SNAPSHOT] startup failed due to previous errors
2016-09-01 10:04:51,392  WARN context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext: 978 - Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Sep 01 10:04:50 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:415)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:975)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:583)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4763)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5400)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
01-Sep-2016 10:04:51.401 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /Users/neut/Documents/Utils/apache-tomcat-8.5.4/webapps/works-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war has finished in 5,711 ms
```

For completeness, here is my full `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.artdecode.works</groupId>
    <artifactId>works</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Works database</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.commons.version>1.12.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring.commons.version>
        <spring.security.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <neo4j.version>2.3.2</neo4j.version>
        <!--  <sdn.version>4.1.0.M1</sdn.version>  -->
        <sdn.version>4.1.2.RELEASE</sdn.version>
        <neo4j.ogm.version>2.0.4</neo4j.ogm.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- J2EE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


       <!-- Spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
             <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>${sdn.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
            <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Neo4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-test</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.ogm.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-harness</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>${sdn.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Others -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>neo4j</id>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>

        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>

        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>

</pluginRepositories>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.6.5.v20120716</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                    <jvmArgs></jvmArgs>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>username</name>
                            <value>neo4j</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>password</name>
                            <value>neo</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Update 2: Here is my Neo4jConfiguration class:

```
/*
 * Copyright [2011-2016] "Neo Technology"
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
 *
 */
package de.artdecode.works;

import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("de.artdecode.works.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("de.artdecode.works.domain")
public class Application extends Neo4jConfiguration {

  public static final int NEO4J_PORT = 7474;

  @Override
  @Bean
  public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return new SessionFactory("de.artdecode.works.domain");
  }


  @Override
  @Bean
  @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
  public Session getSession() throws Exception {
    return super.getSession();
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your Neo4jConfiguration class look like?

Comment: Just posted it under "Update 2".

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using version 4.1.2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, adding the Bolt driver dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

should not produce any version conflicts.

Here's an example of a minimal ogm.properties file for Bolt:

```
driver=org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver
URI=bolt://neo4j:password@localhost
encryption.level=NONE
```

**Edit**: I've upgraded the cineasts project here https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-cineasts/tree/4.2 to work with SDN 4.2.0.M1 and the Bolt driver.

And the 4.1 branch is based on SDN 4.1.2 and OGM 2.0.3 https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-cineasts/tree/4.1

With both branches, all tests pass and http://localhost:8080/movies?q=matrix produce no exceptions.

Note that there is a problem with SDN 4.1.2 and OGM 2.0.4. This has been fixed in SDN 4.1.3-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Thanks, but this fails to deploy, see my update above.  In the meantime, I have built the original, unmodified sdn4-cineasts example, but am getting "HTTP ERROR 405, Problem accessing /auth/denied. Reason: Request method 'POST' not supported" errors on registration and login. So I suspect that I tried to use an example that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I have concluded that I can't get Bolt to work at Spring 4.1.2.RELEASE. I'm now using the HTTP driver without a problem.

Comment: please see my edited answer, I've upgraded cineasts dependencies

Comment: I'm having the same problems with 4.1.2 and the bolt driver. Let's wait for a proper solution.